# how to update many integer values back to their respective columns in database in C#

Tags: c#

i have datagrid that load information from database and when each row is selected like this each columns shows in one textbox1 like this;

```
private void dgvGrade_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
    DataRowView dr = dg.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
    if (dr != null)
    {
        
        if (dgvGrade.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var obj in dgvGrade.SelectedItems)
            {
                //txtids.Text += dr["IDNO"].ToString();
                str += dr["ENGLISH"] + "   " + dr["MATH"] + "    " + dr["SOCIAL"] + "   " + dr["SCIENCE"] + "   " + dr["PRETECH"] + "   " + dr["ICT"] + "   " + dr["RME"] + "  " + dr["HOMEECOMICS"] + "  " + dr["HISTORY"] + "   " + dr["OWOP"] + "   " + dr["CREATIVEART"] + "   " + dr["FRENCH"] + "   " + dr["LANGUAGE"] + " " + " ";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //DO NOTHING
        }
        txtresults.Text = str;
    }
```

and after changes each digit in the textbox1 i would like to save each value back to the database to each column so i tried this;

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(shoolmanangmentconn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    Conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tbl_TestingTheApplicationSubject SET MATH=@MATH, ENGLISH=@ENGLISH, SOCIAL=@SOCIAL, SCIENCE=@SCIENCE, RME=@RME, PRETECH=@PRETECH, HOMEECOMICS=@HOMEECOMICS,  HISTORY=@HISTORY, OWOP=@OWOP, ICT=@ICT, FRENCH=@FRENCH, CREATIVEART=@CREATIVEART, LANGUAGE=@LANGUAGE WHERE IDNO IN (@IDNO)", Conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    string[] arryval = txtresults.Text.Split(new[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int i = 0;
    String IDNO = "123,567,89";
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDNO",IDNO)**; // TODO: use correct value of IDNO
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ENGLISH", arryval[i++]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MATH", arryval[i++]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SOCIAL", arryval[i++]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SCIENCE", arryval[i++]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRETECH", arryval[i++]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ICT", arryval[i++]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RME", arryval[i++]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HOMEECOMICS", arryval[i++]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HISTORY", arryval[i++]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OWOP", arryval[i++]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREATIVEART", arryval[i++]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FRENCH", arryval[i++]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LANGUAGE", arryval[i++]);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but i end up saving only one row in its IDNO columns but i have many IDNO columns selected as well but i don't know how to save each row back according to there IDNO Numbers please can some one help me out please (am using c# wpf)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is this part of your SQL query `IDNO=@IDNO`. When using the `=` operator, only one specific value can be provided to compare against. Since you want to update multiple records, you should use the [`IN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) operator instead like this `IDNO IN (@IDNO)`. Then you'll need to construct a comma separated list of IDs as a string for `@IDNO` which you can add as the parameter. For example, `@IDNO` should look something like this `"123, 723, 987"` (with your data's actual IDs) before you add it to your command's parameters.

Comment: that didn't work for me please can you suggest another option for me please

Comment: @KcisraelKicsoAcquah Can you please update your post with the new code you tried and also the value of `@IDNO`?

Comment: please sir i just updated the code as from your previous suggestion but i believe am wrong some where please sir am new here can you help me immensely please.

Comment: @KcisraelKicsoAcquah Yes I'd like to help, I'm just unsure of your issue with the new code. Could you please show me what the value of `@IDNO` is?

Comment: ok to be lucid; the value of the @IDNO is loaded into the a different textbox simultaneously as each row from the datagrid is selected; i have

Comment: please did you get my comment ?

Comment: @KcisraelKicsoAcquah I did see your comment but I don't see the value for `@IDNO`. It's important you paste an exact copy of it's contents, as that could affect the query.

Comment: the value of @IDNO is been piled up in a seperate textbox like this; 1, 2,3,4 etc. as there respective rows from datagrid in my project so i have txtids.text += dr["IDNO"];

Comment: @KcisraelKicsoAcquah I understand, and I see your update with the example `@IDNO`. What does it do when you run that code now (it looks correct)?

Comment: You cannot use a single parameter to hold a list of values for use in an IN clause. You could build a command string with a list of parameters there (one for each value) and supply values for each separate parameter

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Why?...does SqlCommand literally convert it to a single string when it injects the parameter I suppose?

Comment: @J.D. Yes, that `@IDNO` holds a single string value as far as SqlServer knows, not a list of ints

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Good point, lame of SqlCommand lol.

Answer (score 0):

You have a string IDNO with value `"123,567,89"`, and you want to use in in a sql query like `... WHERE IDNO IN (@IDNO)` to get `... WHERE IDNO IN (123,567,89)`.

Sorry, you cannot do that. A parameter can hold only a single value and it will not get expanded to a list of values for use in an IN clause. As far as SqlServer knows, it is just a single (n)varchar value, not a list of ints.

What you *can* do however is generate a series of placeholders, so that your command string fragment will look like `... WHERE IDNO IN (@p0, @p1, @p2)` (one `@p<n>` for each of the values in your IDNO variable.

- First split the IDNO value using

```
string[] stringvals = IDNO.Split(",");
```

- Then generate placeholders and add them to your query

```
var placeholders = string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(0, stringvals.Length).Select(n => $"@p{n}"));
var sql = $"UPDATE tbl_TestingTheApplicationSubject SET ... WHERE IDNO IN ({placeholders})";
```

- Create SqlParameters for each, specifying the corresponding value from stringvals, *converted to int*.

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add($"@p{n}", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(stringvals[n]);
```

Possible alternative: [Table Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine).